# MPV takes too long to load a video

Tags: xubuntu, video, macbook, mpv-media-player

I have Xubuntu 16.04.4 installed in a MacBook white (2007 model).

Everything works fine.

There is only an annoying issue.

MPV takes forever to load any video, irrespective of the video file size. I am talking about 30 seconds to open each video.

I am forced to use VLC in this machine, but I would rather use MPV.

Does anyone know about a fix for this?

Comment: go `mpv --log-file=mpv.log --no-config  /path/to/filename`  You'll then find a log in home folder.  Copy to a pastebin like https://paste.ubuntu.com/  & post link to it.

Comment: How long do the videos take to load in vlc? Does this happen if you try to open a video in vlc first and then open it in mpv?

Comment: @ianorlin, videos load instantly in vlc. If I open the video file in vlc and then in mpv it is the same.

Comment: @doug here it is --> https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/SjmHkJZyWK/

Comment: That version of mpv is ancient & honestly I've no idea about using Xubuntu on apple hardware.. i've a ppa for mpv, you could take a read thru here, if deciding to try then use the same command & see if any improvement, - https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/mpv-tests

Comment: @doug, Thank you so much! It is working flawlessly now. I don't know what's the deal with the "official" Xubuntu repositories since they only offer an ancient version of MPV. Thank you, man.